# github beautiful popup: looking for css

Tags: css, github, popup, leaflet, mapbox

There is a new feature on Github : [maps](https://github.com/blog/1528-there-s-a-map-for-that). It's built with Leaflet, but it clearly uses some costum css for the pop-up:

[image]

I would love to use the same, but I can't find the relevant css.

Comment: The content inside of popup can vary, so are you saying about the popup structure? I mean, the container? Or the container plus what have inside of it?

Comment: Using the element inspector within your browser on the example shown on Leafletjs.com will show you the relevant css.

Comment: @chiefGui The container and the nice table.

Comment: @dmc looking into it. I had a bug with firebug at first..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page as example

[`lpfm_points.geojson`](http://github.com/FCC/lpfmpoints/blob/gh-pages/data/lpfm_points.geojson)

Contains a link

[`geojson`](http://render.github.com/view/geojson?url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.github.com%2FFCC%2Flpfmpoints%2Fgh-pages%2Fdata%2Flpfm_points.geojson)

On that page is the dynamically generated CSS

[`geojson-64e8fd6d2ba99bc02ad3b29de0f16e1a.css`](https://render.github.com/assets/geojson-64e8fd6d2ba99bc02ad3b29de0f16e1a.css)

Snippet

```css
.marker-properties td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee; }
```